# Equation numbers in loop

Tags: equations, programming

I am using the loop command to make an exam file with unique numbers, i.e., the whole exam text is repated and only the first page of the exam looks different. I am using equation numbers in the text and the labels are multiple defined because of the loop, so they are all linking to the last one and the numbers is very big in the last exams.

Do you have any idea how to overcome this problem? Thanks a lot!

edit: Here is an example: http://blubb-bla.de/pk_test_tex.pdf

edit2: Here is the code:

`\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt,DIV=14]{scrartcl}

\setcounter{numsoll}{25} 

\begin{document}

\loop

You are number \arabic{numakt}.

\begin{align} a = b \label{eq} \end{align}

Reference \eqref{eq}.

\pagebreak


\ifnum\value{numakt}<\value{numsoll}

\stepcounter{numakt}

\repeat

\end{document}`

Comment: An example seems necessary.

Comment: I've made an example from my existing file. Sorry for the German in the example. You have to look at page 2,4, etc.

Comment: Sorry, but we need some code, not the final result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This repeats a block of text while resetting all latex counters so the same values are used each time round, and disabling `\label` so labels are not multiply defined.
Without a real example it's something of a guess if this is related to your problem though.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\savecounters{{%
\def\@elt##1{\global\value{##1}\the\value{##1}\relax}%
\xdef\resetcounters{\cl@@ckpt}}}
\makeatother

\newcount\lpcnt
\begin{document}




\savecounters
\lpcnt=1
\loop
\ifnum\lpcnt<5
\advance\lpcnt by 1
\resetcounters

\begin{equation}
1=2\label{a}
\end{equation}

Equation \ref{a} is wrong.
\renewcommand\label[1]{}
\repeat

\end{document}
```